# Jenkins job is not stopping after completion of execution

Tags: jenkins

I am running Jenkins using maven and once the job is completed it is not terminating until we terminate it manually.In console output able to see the results but not showing build success and showing the processing symbol/loading symbol. can any one tell me how to stop the job after job execution.[image]
Do we need to terminate manually or 
do we have need to add anything in post build to stop after successful execution?
do we have to set something in configuration to terminate automatically

please can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things could be going on here:

- Does the Maven build execute any other goals after running tests ?  If so those could be hanging.
- Does your build run on a slave ?  If so, Jenkins copies log files and other artifacts back to the master after completing the build steps but before marking the build as complete.  You may have a network or I/O bottleneck here.

If you can't figure out the root cause and just want to have the build terminate without intervention, you can use the [build timeout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

If you have jobs running in parallell then some plugins have to wait for the older jobs to finish until the current one can. Not sure if this is your situation.

Answer (score 0):

After using webdriver.quit() in our selenium project, it's working fine.Job got completed and the reports were generated.